# Do Catholic priests have to report child abuse confessed in secret?

Tags: catholicism, children, confession

Is there any canon, regulation, norm or diocesan norm which requires priests to report confessions of child abuse?  Are priests obliged to follow laws to this effect?

I'm not asking in regard to child sexual abuse committed by other priests as has been reported in the news over the last decade or so, but the kind of stuff that, if someone came to a physician or a psychologist for help with, the person involved would have to report to authorities.

Comment: I assume you're asking for answers from the perspective of the church, not the law-makers? But a small point re the start of your second paragraph: the complicating factor is that in many cases it has come to light that the offender *has* confessed to fellow priests on the matter - so in many ways it can still be relevant.

Comment: Yeah, I almost said obliged to follow "human law" but I thought it wasn't necessary to say human here. But on the second part of your comment, I'm specifically not asking about priest confessions, just confessions of the laity.

Comment: Here's a relevant news story: http://www.catholicsun.org/2014/07/09/court-may-compel-priest-to-break-confessional-seal-in-abuse-case/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Within the Confessional

Canon Law specifically and absolutely forbids the priest from divulging anything sacramentally confessed ([Can 983](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P3G.HTM)).

That said, and notwithstanding Canon 980, it would be possible for a priest to withhold absolution from a penitent until she has reported any crime to the authorities herself. The priest may legitimately have doubts about the penitent's penitence until she accepts the consequences of her actions.

I have been told that if a priest has plans to travel on a particular plane, and someone sacramentally confesses that that flight is to be hijacked and brought down, the priest must not alter his own behaviour and travel on a different plane. He must act as if he had heard nothing.

There is scope for conflict with civil law. In the United Kingdom, it is not normally an offence *not* to report criminal activity, but terrorism, money-laundering, treason and the failure to lawfully dispose of a body must be reported. A priest who hears such a confession is bound by civil law to report the crime and by canon law not to do so. Other countries may expand that list of applicable crimes.

#### Outside the Confessional

The requirement to maintain the secrecy of the sacramental confession does not bind anything confessed outside the sacrament of Reconciliation.

In the United Kingdom, it is not a criminal offence not to report or make an allegation of child abuse. Even if such a report is made, a priest could not give evidence such as "X told me that she had," because that's hearsay. Additional primary evidence would be required.

In England and Wales, the Catholic Safeguarding Advisory Service [says](http://www.csasprocedures.uk.net/chapters/p_chi_young_peop.html)

> An adult who provides information should be encouraged to share that information with the statutory agencies, where appropriate.
>
> They should be offered support by the Local Safeguarding Representative to do so.
>
> If the adult or child providing information about another child request anonymity when the Safeguarding Officer makes the referral to Children's Social Care Services or the Police, those agencies will respect their wishes as far as possible. However, where investigations proceed to Court this may not be possible to maintain at all times.
>
> An adult in an official or lay position of trust within the Church cannot expect to remain anonymous when a referral is made.

In the case of an offender confessing outside the Confessional, there is a duty to report, and to encourage the offender to tell the authorities herself.

Comment: "I have been told that if a priest has plans to travel... the priest must not alter his own behaviour and travel on a different plane. He must act as if he had heard nothing."

That is a popular saying, and even some priests will say it, but it is not in the canons. Canons 983-84 give clear regulation for the use of knowledge gained in condition. It can be used - though of course, never in a way that reveals a penitent's identity or sins.

See: http://www.intratext.com/IXT/ENG0017/_P3F.HTM

Comment: For example, can. 984 §1 states, "The confessor is wholly forbidden to use knowledge acquired in confession *to the detriment of the penitent*, even when all danger of disclosure is excluded."

This specifically means that it might be used in other ways not to the detriment of the penitent. For instance, the priest might call and place an anonymous tip that there is a terror plot. In a society where his religious obligation will be respected, he might do so personally. In doing so, he neither betrays the penitent nor abdicates authentic social responsibility.

Comment: The physical location of a confessional is not the sacrosanct thing; it is the act of sacramental confession. The sacramental confession might take place discreetly in a shopping mall, and be perfectly valid, and completely protected by the law of God and His Church. If someone mentions having done a crime, or knowing such information, outside of the context of a sacramental confession, then the canons clearly do not protect such communications. They are confessions in one sense, but not in the sense meant when we talk about the sacrament.

Comment: I think the issue of how and where a confession is sacramental belongs in another question. [What makes a confession sacramental?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/9943)

Comment: @Ryan See Cann 984 §2 and 964 §3 (and 964 §1). However these are better raised in another question than comments. And I see there is one: [What makes a confession sacramental?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/9943)

Comment: @AndrewLeach, yeah, but that "without a just cause" is a HUGE *nisi*. It doesn't even require a proportional cause - only a just one, a "good reason" if you will. It's one of the lower levels of countervailing exigency. That's the same phrase that allows a bishop to let his priests celebrate Mass more than once in a day, which is, as you know, very common.

Comment: Can 984 §2 excludes from use in external governance knowledge gained in confession - not the confessional.

Comment: Ah. I think you're ascribing undue significance to the subheadings in my answer. They were a shorthand for "Within the Sacrament of Reconciliation" (although the Canons do say that the proper place is in the confessional, and every church must have at least one with a fixed grille). A confession can indeed be sacramental elsewhere.

Comment: @Caleb, it's actually really very pertinent here whether a confession is sacramental or not because only a confession intended to be sacramental is protected by the seal of confession. If you just call up a priest randomly and say, "Hey, Father, I'm Caleb and I killed a man. You can find the body at this address," there is no canonical protection for the confession. (see Can.  983 §1. *The sacramental seal is inviolable;*)

Comment: I saw on old Mattlock or Diagnosis Murder episode where a murderer is fleeing the scene and is caught by a priest. The murderer immediately falls to his knees and begins confessing. The priest, bound by the Canon law, remains silent about who he saw, even after *he, himself,* was accused of the murder. Is this even a scenario that is possible, or could the priest refuse to hear the confession then report the murder?

Comment: A different question: You said in a comment that every church must have a confessional with a fixed grille. I remember my church had a room with a portable screen and you could stay behind it or sit face to face with the priest. Are you sure a fixed grille is mandatory?

Comment: @fredsbend Fixed grille, easy: [Canon 964](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P3F.HTM). Unconventional confession, less easy, but Canon 964 could be brought to bear there too. Canon 986 allows the setting of a particular time and place for confessions to be heard.

Comment: *The confessor is wholly forbidden to use knowledge acquired in confession to the detriment of the penitent,* Shouldn't that then allow priests to report crimes? The state using its God-given authority to punish and discipline wrongdoers is not detrimental to them. In fact helping them avoid rightful discipline is detrimental!

Comment: @AndrewLeach I just saw this answer, and I would like to suggest an edit: actually, no one is ever obligated (morally speaking—legally, it may be a different matter) to turn himself in, and so no, a priest could not withhold absolution on condition that the penitent turn himself in to the authority.

In any event, even if the priest were to withhold absolution for some reason (which has to be, essentially, because the penitent is not repentant), what he has heard in the context of confession is still under the seal.

Comment: @AndrewLeach The more common case, actually, is that the penitent somehow reveals that he has been abused. Obviously, this is not a question of turning himself in—but a case which, in many jurisdictions, the priest may be legally obligated (in the civil law) to report. _Within the context of Confession_, the priest is bound absolutely by the seal, and so—civil law notwithstanding—he must never reveal the secret. However, the correct procedure would be for the priest to explain to that he cannot break the seal, advising the penitent to report the matter and seek professional help.

Comment: @AndrewLeach For instance, the priest could say, “I advise you to bring this up to me again outside of confession” (explaining, of course, that he would then be required to report it, if that is the case).

Answer (score 4):

If a priest violates the seal of confession, he is automatically excommunicated, period. Even if someone confesses to being a rapist, serial killer that enjoys hitting kittens with a baseball bat, the priest violates the seal of confession, that priest is *still excommunicated*.

---

There are norms for the reporting of child abuse (and often if a child is willing to mention something in confession, the child will be willing to mention something while *not* in confession) which have developed over the past couple of decades and they vary from diocese to diocese. Paterson diocese, for example, has the standard of "If you suspect a child is being harmed, call DYFS immediately, then call <the person in charge of this type of investigation at the diocesan level>." They've actually put posters up saying this. While I cannot imagine Newark diocese being any different, they have not put up posters (to my knowledge).

Answer (score 1):

No.
What is said during the Sacrament of Penance, must be secret and it's inviolable.
The Seal of Confession must not be violated, no matter how serious is the fault, not even if it could save another life.
The priest cannot disclose anything that is said during a Penance, directly or indirectly. To make an extreme example, if a man, during the Penance, confess to put poison in the chalice that will be used in the next mass, the priest cannot warn anyone about that, or clean it, or do anything about it.
That's it. He can't save a life.
 He can only put the absolution under a condition: "clean the poison and save the priest, then God will forgive you".

Wikipedia explains well this concept, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_of_the_Confessional_and_the_Catholic_Church)